# pyenv install 3.11 stay stuck at Installing Python-3.11.7

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyenv

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and when i use the command :

`pyenv install 3.11`

It stays blocked like this :

> ubuntu@instance:~$ pyenv install 3.11
>
> Downloading Python-3.11.7.tar.xz...
>
> -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.7/Python-3.11.7.tar.xz
>
> Installing Python-3.11.7...

After waiting a while I decide to abort using `CTRL + C` and I get this error :

```
ubuntu@instance:\~$ pyenv install 3.11

Downloading Python-3.11.7.tar.xz...

\-\> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.7/Python-3.11.7.tar.xz

Installing Python-3.11.7...

^C

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20231216055700.26655

Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20231216055700.26655.log

Last 10 log lines:

checking for curses function wchgat... yes

checking for curses function filter... yes

checking for curses function has_key... yes

checking for curses function typeahead... yes

checking for curses function use_env... yes

configure: checking for device files

checking for /dev/ptmx... yes

checking for /dev/ptc... no

checking for %zd printf() format support... yes
```

I have obviously checked the log file and found :

```
cat /tmp/python-build.20231216055700.26655.log

/tmp/python-build.20231216055700.26655 \~
/tmp/python-build.20231216055700.26655/Python-3.11.7 /tmp/python-build.20231216055700.26655 \~
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for Python interpreter freezing... ./\_bootstrap_python
checking for python3.11... python3.11
checking Python for regen version... Python 3.11.7
checking for pkg-config... /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "linux"
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for CC compiler name... gcc
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for --with-cxx-main=\<compiler\>... no
checking for g++... no
configure:

By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".
If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... x86_64-linux-gnu
checking for multiarch... x86_64-linux-gnu
checking for PEP 11 support tier... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc has tier 1 (supported)
checking for -Wl,--no-as-needed... yes
checking for the Android API level... not Android
checking for --with-emscripten-target...
checking for --enable-wasm-dynamic-linking... missing
checking for --enable-wasm-pthreads... missing
checking for --with-suffix...
checking for case-insensitive build directory... no
checking LIBRARY... libpython$(VERSION)$(ABIFLAGS).a
checking LINKCC... $(PURIFY) $(MAINCC)
checking EXPORTSYMS...
checking for GNU ld... yes
checking for --enable-shared... yes
checking for --with-static-libpython... yes
checking for --enable-profiling... no
checking LDLIBRARY... checking HOSTRUNNER...
libpython$(LDVERSION).so
checking for ar... ar
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for --with-pydebug... no
checking for --with-trace-refs... no
checking for --enable-pystats... no
checking for --with-assertions... no
checking for --enable-optimizations... no
checking PROFILE_TASK... -m test --pgo --timeout=$(TESTTIMEOUT)
checking for --with-lto... no
checking for llvm-profdata... no
checking if gcc supports -Og optimization level... yes
checking if we can add -Wextra... yes
checking whether gcc -fno-strict-aliasing accepts and needs -fno-strict-aliasing... no
checking if we can disable gcc unused-parameter warning... yes
checking if we can disable gcc int-conversion warning... yes
checking if we can disable gcc missing-field-initializers warning... yes
checking if we can enable gcc sign-compare warning... yes
checking if we can enable gcc unreachable-code warning... yes
checking if we can enable gcc strict-prototypes warning... no
checking if we can make implicit function declaration an error in gcc -Werror=implicit-function-declaration... yes
checking if we can use visibility in gcc -fvisibility=hidden... yes
checking whether pthreads are available without options... yes
checking whether g++ also accepts flags for thread support... no
checking alloca.h usability... yes
checking alloca.h presence... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking asm/types.h usability... yes
checking asm/types.h presence... yes
checking for asm/types.h... yes
checking bluetooth.h usability... no
checking bluetooth.h presence... no
checking for bluetooth.h... no
checking conio.h usability... no
checking conio.h presence... no
checking for conio.h... no
checking crypt.h usability... yes
checking crypt.h presence... yes
checking for crypt.h... yes
checking direct.h usability... no
checking direct.h presence... no
checking for direct.h... no
checking ieeefp.h usability... no
checking ieeefp.h presence... no
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking io.h usability... no
checking io.h presence... no
checking for io.h... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking libutil.h usability... no
checking libutil.h presence... no
checking for libutil.h... no
checking linux/auxvec.h usability... yes
checking linux/auxvec.h presence... yes
checking for linux/auxvec.h... yes
checking sys/auxv.h usability... yes
checking sys/auxv.h presence... yes
checking for sys/auxv.h... yes
checking linux/limits.h usability... yes
checking linux/limits.h presence... yes
checking for linux/limits.h... yes
checking linux/memfd.h usability... yes
checking linux/memfd.h presence... yes
checking for linux/memfd.h... yes
checking linux/random.h usability... yes
checking linux/random.h presence... yes
checking for linux/random.h... yes
checking linux/soundcard.h usability... yes
checking linux/soundcard.h presence... yes
checking for linux/soundcard.h... yes
checking linux/tipc.h usability... yes
checking linux/tipc.h presence... yes
checking for linux/tipc.h... yes
checking linux/wait.h usability... yes
checking linux/wait.h presence... yes
checking for linux/wait.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking netpacket/packet.h usability... yes
checking netpacket/packet.h presence... yes
checking for netpacket/packet.h... yes
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking process.h usability... no
checking process.h presence... no
checking for process.h... no
checking stropts.h usability... no
checking stropts.h presence... no
checking for stropts.h... no
checking sys/audioio.h usability... no
checking sys/audioio.h presence... no
checking for sys/audioio.h... no
checking sys/bsdtty.h usability... no
checking sys/bsdtty.h presence... no
checking for sys/bsdtty.h... no
checking sys/devpoll.h usability... no
checking sys/devpoll.h presence... no
checking for sys/devpoll.h... no
checking sys/endian.h usability... no
checking sys/endian.h presence... no
checking for sys/endian.h... no
checking sys/epoll.h usability... yes
checking sys/epoll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/epoll.h... yes
checking sys/event.h usability... no
checking sys/event.h presence... no
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking sys/eventfd.h usability... yes
checking sys/eventfd.h presence... yes
checking for sys/eventfd.h... yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/kern_control.h usability... no
checking sys/kern_control.h presence... no
checking for sys/kern_control.h... no
checking sys/loadavg.h usability... no
checking sys/loadavg.h presence... no
checking for sys/loadavg.h... no
checking sys/lock.h usability... no
checking sys/lock.h presence... no
checking for sys/lock.h... no
checking sys/memfd.h usability... no
checking sys/memfd.h presence... no
checking for sys/memfd.h... no
checking sys/mkdev.h usability... no
checking sys/mkdev.h presence... no
checking for sys/mkdev.h... no
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking sys/modem.h usability... no
checking sys/modem.h presence... no
checking for sys/modem.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/poll.h usability... yes
checking sys/poll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking sys/random.h usability... yes
checking sys/random.h presence... yes
checking for sys/random.h... yes
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/sendfile.h usability... yes
checking sys/sendfile.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sendfile.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/soundcard.h usability... yes
checking sys/soundcard.h presence... yes
checking for sys/soundcard.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/statvfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking sys/sys_domain.h usability... no
checking sys/sys_domain.h presence... no
checking for sys/sys_domain.h... no
checking sys/syscall.h usability... yes
checking sys/syscall.h presence... yes
checking for sys/syscall.h... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysmacros.h... yes
checking sys/termio.h usability... no
checking sys/termio.h presence... no
checking for sys/termio.h... no
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/uio.h usability... yes
checking sys/uio.h presence... yes
checking for sys/uio.h... yes
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking sys/wait.h usability... yes
checking sys/wait.h presence... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking sys/xattr.h usability... yes
checking sys/xattr.h presence... yes
checking for sys/xattr.h... yes
checking sysexits.h usability... yes
checking sysexits.h presence... yes
checking for sysexits.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking util.h usability... no
checking util.h presence... no
checking for util.h... no
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking utmp.h usability... yes
checking utmp.h presence... yes
checking for utmp.h... yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking whether sys/types.h defines makedev... no
checking for sys/mkdev.h... (cached) no
checking for sys/sysmacros.h... (cached) yes
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h usability... no
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h presence... no
checking for bluetooth/bluetooth.h... no
checking for net/if.h... yes
checking for linux/netlink.h... yes
checking for linux/qrtr.h... yes
checking for linux/vm_sockets.h... yes
checking for linux/can.h... yes
checking for linux/can/bcm.h... yes
checking for linux/can/j1939.h... yes
checking for linux/can/raw.h... yes
checking for netcan/can.h... no
checking for clock_t in time.h... yes
checking for makedev... yes
checking for le64toh... yes
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for \__uint128_t... yes
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking alignment of long... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of void \*... 8
checking size of short... 2
checking size of float... 4
checking size of double... 8
checking size of fpos_t... 16
checking size of size_t... 8
checking alignment of size_t... 8
checking size of pid_t... 4
checking size of uintptr_t... 8
checking for long double... yes
checking size of long double... 16
checking size of \_Bool... 1
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... no
checking size of time_t... 8
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 8
checking size of pthread_key_t... 4
checking whether pthread_key_t is compatible with int... yes
checking for --enable-framework... no
checking for dyld... no
checking for --with-address-sanitizer... no
checking for --with-memory-sanitizer... no
checking for --with-undefined-behavior-sanitizer... no
checking the extension of shared libraries... .so
checking LDSHARED... $(CC) -shared
checking BLDSHARED flags... $(CC) -shared
checking CCSHARED... -fPIC
checking LINKFORSHARED... -Xlinker -export-dynamic
checking CFLAGSFORSHARED... $(CCSHARED)
checking SHLIBS... $(LIBS)
checking for sendfile in -lsendfile... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking uuid.h usability... no
checking uuid.h presence... no
checking for uuid.h... no
checking for LIBUUID... yes
checking for library containing sem_init... none required
checking for textdomain in -lintl... no
checking aligned memory access is required... no
checking for --with-hash-algorithm... default
checking for --with-tzpath... "/usr/share/zoneinfo:/usr/lib/zoneinfo:/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo:/etc/zoneinfo"
checking for t_open in -lnsl... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for --with-libs... no
checking for --with-system-expat... no
checking for --with-system-ffi... yes
checking for --with-system-libmpdec... no
checking for --with-decimal-contextvar... yes
checking for decimal libmpdec machine... uint128
checking for LIBNSL... no
checking for library containing yp_match... -lnsl
checking rpc/rpc.h usability... no
checking rpc/rpc.h presence... no
checking for rpc/rpc.h... no
checking for LIBSQLITE3... yes
checking sqlite3.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_bind_double in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_decltype in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_double in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_complete in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_enable_shared_cache in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_progress_handler in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_result_double in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_set_authorizer in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_trace_v2 in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_value_double in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_serialize in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions... no
checking for TCLTK... yes
checking gdbm.h usability... yes
checking gdbm.h presence... yes
checking for gdbm.h... yes
checking for gdbm_open in -lgdbm... yes
checking ndbm.h usability... no
checking ndbm.h presence... no
checking for ndbm.h... no
checking gdbm/ndbm.h usability... no
checking gdbm/ndbm.h presence... no
checking for gdbm/ndbm.h... no
checking gdbm-ndbm.h usability... no
checking gdbm-ndbm.h presence... no
checking for gdbm-ndbm.h... no
checking db.h usability... no
checking db.h presence... no
checking for db.h... no
checking for --with-dbmliborder... gdbm:ndbm:bdb
checking if PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM is supported... yes
checking for pthread_sigmask... yes
checking for pthread_getcpuclockid... yes
checking if --enable-ipv6 is specified... yes
checking if RFC2553 API is available... yes
checking ipv6 stack type... linux-glibc
checking CAN_RAW_FD_FRAMES... yes
checking for CAN_RAW_JOIN_FILTERS... yes
checking for --with-doc-strings... yes
checking for --with-pymalloc... yes
checking for --with-freelists... yes
checking for --with-c-locale-coercion... yes
checking for --with-valgrind... no
checking for --with-dtrace... no
checking for dlopen... yes
checking DYNLOADFILE... dynload_shlib.o
checking MACHDEP_OBJS... none
checking for accept4... yes
checking for alarm... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for chmod... yes
checking for chown... yes
checking for clock... yes
checking for close_range... yes
checking for confstr... yes
checking for copy_file_range... yes
checking for ctermid... yes
checking for dup... yes
checking for dup3... yes
checking for execv... yes
checking for explicit_bzero... yes
checking for explicit_memset... no
checking for faccessat... yes
checking for fchmod... yes
checking for fchmodat... yes
checking for fchown... yes
checking for fchownat... yes
checking for fdopendir... yes
checking for fdwalk... no
checking for fexecve... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking for fork1... no
checking for getpriority... yes
checking for \_getpty... no
checking for getpwent... yes
checking for getpwnam_r... yes
checking for getpwuid... yes
checking for getpwuid_r... yes
checking for getresgid... yes
checking for getresuid... yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for getsid... yes
checking for getspent... yes
checking for getspnam... yes
checking for getuid... yes
checking for getwd... yes
checking for plock... no
checking for poll... yes
checking for posix_fadvise... yes
checking for posix_fallocate... yes
checking for posix_spawn... yes
checking for posix_spawnp... yes
checking for pread... yes
checking for preadv... yes
checking for preadv2... yes
checking for pthread_condattr_setclock... yes
checking for pthread_init... no
checking for pthread_kill... yes
checking for pwrite... yes
checking for pwritev... yes
checking for pwritev2... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking for readlinkat... yes
checking for readv... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for renameat... yes
checking for rtpSpawn... no
checking for sched_get_priority_max... yes
checking for sched_rr_get_interval... yes
checking for sched_setaffinity... yes
checking for sched_setparam... yes
checking for sched_setscheduler... yes
checking for sem_clockwait... yes
checking for sem_getvalue... yes
checking for sem_open... yes
checking for sem_timedwait... yes
checking for sem_unlink... yes
checking for sendfile... yes
checking for setegid... yes
checking for seteuid... yes
checking for setgid... yes
checking for sethostname... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for setpgid... yes
checking for setpgrp... yes
checking for setpriority... yes
checking for setregid... yes
checking for setresgid... yes
checking for setresuid... yes
checking for setreuid... yes
checking for setsid... yes
checking for setuid... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for shutdown... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sigaltstack... yes
checking for sigfillset... yes
checking for siginterrupt... yes
checking for sigpending... yes
checking for sigrelse... yes
checking for sigtimedwait... yes
checking for sigwait... yes
checking for sigwaitinfo... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for splice... yes
checking for strftime... yes
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for strsignal... yes
checking for symlinkat... yes
checking for sync... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for system... yes
checking for tcgetpgrp... yes
checking for tcsetpgrp... yes
checking for tempnam... yes
checking for timegm... yes
checking for times... yes
checking for tmpfile... yes
checking for tmpnam... yes
checking for tmpnam_r... yes
checking for truncate... yes
checking for ttyname... yes
checking for umask... yes
checking for uname... yes
checking for unlinkat... yes
checking for utimensat... yes
checking for utimes... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for wait... yes
checking for wait3... yes
checking for wait4... yes
checking for waitid... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for wcscoll... yes
checking for wcsftime... yes
checking for wcsxfrm... yes
checking for wmemcmp... yes
checking for writev... yes
checking whether dirfd is declared... yes
checking for chroot... yes
checking for link... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for fchdir... yes
checking for fsync... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for epoll_create... yes
checking for epoll_create1... yes
checking for kqueue... no
checking for prlimit... yes
checking for \_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path... no
checking for memfd_create... yes
checking for eventfd... yes
checking for ctermid_r... no
checking for flock declaration... yes
checking for flock... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for broken unsetenv... no
checking for true... true
checking for inet_aton in -lc... yes
checking for chflags... no
checking for lchflags... no
checking for ZLIB... yes
checking for BZIP2... yes
checking for LIBLZMA... yes
checking for hstrerror... yes
checking for getservbyname... yes
checking for getservbyport... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for gethostbyaddr... yes
checking for getprotobyname... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for getpeername... (cached) yes
checking for getsockname... yes
checking for accept... yes
checking for bind... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for listen... yes
checking for recvfrom... yes
checking for sendto... yes
checking for setsockopt... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for setgroups... yes
checking for openpty... yes
checking for library containing login_tty... none required
checking for forkpty... yes
checking for fseek64... no
checking for fseeko... yes
checking for fstatvfs... yes
checking for ftell64... no
checking for ftello... yes
checking for statvfs... yes
checking for dup2... yes
checking for getpgrp... yes
checking for setpgrp... (cached) yes
checking for LIBCRYPT... yes
checking for crypt or crypt_r... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for clock_getres... yes
checking for clock_settime... yes
checking for clock_nanosleep... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for major, minor, and makedev... yes
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking getaddrinfo bug... no
checking for getnameinfo... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for struct stat.st_rdev... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for struct stat.st_flags... no
checking for struct stat.st_gen... no
checking for struct stat.st_birthtime... no
checking for struct stat.st_blocks... yes
checking for struct passwd.pw_gecos... yes
checking for struct passwd.pw_passwd... yes
checking for siginfo_t.si_band... yes
checking for time.h that defines altzone... no
checking for addrinfo... yes
checking for sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for sockaddr_alg... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for working signed char... yes
checking for prototypes... yes
checking for variable length prototypes and stdarg.h... yes
checking for socketpair... yes
checking if sockaddr has sa_len member... no
checking for gethostbyname_r... yes
checking gethostbyname_r with 6 args... yes
checking for \__fpu_control... yes
checking for --with-libm=STRING... default LIBM="-lm"
checking for --with-libc=STRING... default LIBC=""
checking for x64 gcc inline assembler... yes
checking whether float word ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether we can use gcc inline assembler to get and set x87 control word... yes
checking whether we can use gcc inline assembler to get and set mc68881 fpcr... no
checking for x87-style double rounding... no
checking for acosh... yes
checking for asinh... yes
checking for atanh... yes
checking for erf... yes
checking for erfc... yes
checking for expm1... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking for log2... yes
checking whether POSIX semaphores are enabled... yes
checking for broken sem_getvalue... no
checking whether RTLD_LAZY is declared... yes
checking whether RTLD_NOW is declared... yes
checking whether RTLD_GLOBAL is declared... yes
checking whether RTLD_LOCAL is declared... yes
checking whether RTLD_NODELETE is declared... yes
checking whether RTLD_NOLOAD is declared... yes
checking whether RTLD_DEEPBIND is declared... yes
checking whether RTLD_MEMBER is declared... no
checking digit size for Python's longs... no value specified
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking size of wchar_t... 4
checking whether wchar_t is signed... yes
checking whether wchar_t is usable... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking ABIFLAGS...
checking SOABI... cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu
checking LDVERSION... $(VERSION)$(ABIFLAGS)
checking for --with-platlibdir... no
checking for --with-wheel-pkg-dir... no
checking whether right shift extends the sign bit... yes
checking for getc_unlocked() and friends... yes
checking how to link readline libs... -lreadline
checking whether rl_completion_append_character is declared... yes
checking whether rl_completion_suppress_append is declared... yes
checking for rl_pre_input_hook in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_completion_display_matches_hook in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_resize_terminal in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_completion_matches in -lreadline... yes
checking whether rl_catch_signals is declared... yes
checking for append_history in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_compdisp_func_t... yes
checking for broken nice()... no
checking for broken poll()... no
checking for working tzset()... yes
checking for tv_nsec in struct stat... yes
checking for tv_nsec2 in struct stat... no
checking curses.h usability... yes
checking curses.h presence... yes
checking for curses.h... yes
checking ncurses.h usability... yes
checking ncurses.h presence... yes
checking for ncurses.h... yes
checking for term.h... yes
checking whether mvwdelch is an expression... yes
checking whether WINDOW has \_flags... yes
checking for curses function is_pad... yes
checking for curses function is_term_resized... yes
checking for curses function resize_term... yes
checking for curses function resizeterm... yes
checking for curses function immedok... yes
checking for curses function syncok... yes
checking for curses function wchgat... yes
checking for curses function filter... yes
checking for curses function has_key... yes
checking for curses function typeahead... yes
checking for curses function use_env... yes
configure: checking for device files
checking for /dev/ptmx... yes
checking for /dev/ptc... no
checking for %zd printf() format support... yes
```

I have looked online and I couldn't find any one with the same problem.I have tried to install some of the 'no' listed package but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I usually don't use python but i need to install pyenv to use a tool. I have tried without pyenv and it doesn't work well...

Thank you